# Getting Thumbnail of a model with AR/VR Toolkit?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

It is possible to retrieve a Thumbnail of a model with Forge AR/VR Toolkit(Unity)?

It seems thumbnail can be retrieved with below API, but what about AR/VR toolkit?
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-thumbnail-GET/

Please note that we are using the latest version of AR/VR Toolkit (ForgeARKit-update-6-2018.1.unitypackage) which is retrieving model from 'https://developer-api-**beta**.autodesk.io'.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's no relevant endpoint/Unity script via the AR/VR toolkit you can still retrieve thumbnail for your model via the GET Thumbnail endpoint using the URN as you usually do once it's processed via the Forge Model Derivative service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint for retriving thumbnail in AR/VR Toolkit Api (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1).

But you have the URN of your Model, so why not calling the url directly?
(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html)

Comment: For the 2nd point, do you mean retrieving the whole model? That would be a lot data, as my models are usually large, I need to retrieve a 'small' one for previewing purpose only. That's why I was asking about the thumbnail.

Comment: Nope. There is a get thumbnail endpoint. Therefore you just need your model URN:
url = https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata// {YOUR URN}/thumbnail +(optional)?width=200&height=200&guid=XXYYZZ